# How to detect error caused by proxy in request module of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I would like to detect whether error is caused by proxy.
If so, I need to try secondary proxy.

I set wrong address to cause error intentionally, and I checked error object.
It includes `{code: 'ECONNRESET'}`.
Does it mean proxy error?

```
const request = require("request")

const primary = "http://192.168.1.10:8080"
const secondary = "http://192.168.1.20:8080"

request.get("https://www.google.com", {proxy: primary}, (err, res, body) => {
    if(err && /* error is caused by proxy */ ){
        request.get("https://www.google.com", {proxy: secondary}, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err){
                console.error(err)
                return
            }
            console.log(body)
        })
    }
    console.log(body)
})
```

Error stack

```
{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.10:8080 at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\dev00\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17) at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13) at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13) at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:382:9) at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13) at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8) at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Proxy errors are signified by error code 502. For reference: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-a-proxy-error, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

You can check response status code to validate proxy error and then you can change your proxy to secondary.

```
const request = require("request")

const primary = "http://192.168.1.10:8080"
const secondary = "http://192.168.1.20:8080"

request.get("https://www.google.com", {proxy: primary}, (err, res, body) => {
    if(res.statusCode == 502){
        request.get("https://www.google.com", {proxy: secondary}, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err){
                console.error(err)
                return
            }
            console.log(body)
        })
    }
    console.log(body)
})
```

Comment: Server is down. (cannot connect)

Comment: { Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.10:8080
    at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\dev00\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:382:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }